# UITableViewCell and disappearing separator

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I try to implement my own simple style of cells in my UITableView and I have a problem with separator. Works great with normal view, but when i select a cell it disappears. I try to add to my customSelect view separator, but then I can't see the separator anywhere. How can I add a separator to selected cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [wallMenuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

        MenuItemModel *mItem = [menu.menuPositions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = mItem.displayName;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.70 green:0.70 blue:0.70 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);

        customSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (cell.frame.origin.y), 320, 2)];
        customSeparator.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [customSeparator.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.8)];
        [customSeparator.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
        [customSeparator.layer setShadowRadius:0.8];
        [customSeparator.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customSeparator];

        customSelect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (cell.frame.origin.y+2), cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        //[customSelect addSubview:customSeparator];
        customSelect.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:customSelect];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

And current result:

[image]

Comment: Try moving the separator creation code outside of the if(cell == nil) block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a UIImageView instead of a simple UIView for your separator. Set the Image value (this is important!) instead of backgroundColor value and stretch the image with scale to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your costumSelect is under the contentView of the Cell. I implemented such behaviour before, but I subclassed UITableViewCell. Try to override setSelected method on your custom cell.

Comment: Should i subclassing only a UITableViewCell or should I subclass my UITableView?

Comment: Subclass the UITableViewCell. In the -drawRect method you are able to setup the view and in -setSelected you can change the behaviour and interface of your cell in selected and unselected state. http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score -1):

use tableView.separatorColor (and tableView.separatorStyle) to set a contrasting separator color.  If you're drawing your own separators within the cell, set separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone. Furthermore, setting the selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone will likely help you

Comment: I don't want to simply change color or change standard style. As i said - i want to create my own separator and selection style.

Comment: You should consider using separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone if you're drawing your own separators.  Furthermore, setting the selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone will likely help you